# how to update a node field value with jQuery callback the drupal way?

Tags: 7, javascript, routes

added the callback for jQuery to the hook_menu in my module.

```
// callback for jQuery with nid and new status as arguments
$items['vacancies_manage/status_callback/%/%'] = array(
    'page callback' => '_vacancies_manage_status_update_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1,2), 
    'access callback' => array('manage own vacancies'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
);

return $items;
```

but how do I call this callback from the module using jQuery instead of just the link? Is there a drupal way for this?

Comment: This isn't really a Drupal question. It's more "how do I use jQuery to hit a URL?". See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: I think this is a Drupal question because there might me a drupal hook or something for it. I'll rephrase my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery would be pretty simple, something like this:

```
$('#link-id').click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/vacancies_manage/status_callback/' + id1 + '/' + 'id2', 
    data: {'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2}, 
    success : function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
});
```

You'll need to replace `id1` and `id2` with the arguments appropriate to your situation, and `arg1` and `arg2` with whatever you want your POST vars to contain.

Then you just need to make sure that you callback actually prints directly to the page, and doesn't return the entire rendered Drupal page so that the jQuery code can receive a response:

```
function _vacancies_manage_status_update_callback() {
  // Do something with $_POST vars here

  // Print something, perhaps a status message to be picked up in jQuery
  print 'OK';
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is by using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax). There is a Drupal specific version of this, called [Drupal.ajax](http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x:/misc/ajax.js#l76).